# changed? depreaction Rails 5.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Devise before it saves the record, it checks if attributes changed and if so it performs special actions:

```
def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
  # If the record is new or changed then delay the
  # delivery until the after_commit callback otherwise
  # send now because after_commit will not be called.

  if new_record? || changed?
    pending_notifications << [notification, args]
  else
    # Devise: send emails with background job
    devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
  end
end
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FModels%2FAuthenticatable%3Asend_devise_notification

The following line gives me an depreaction now:

```
if new_record? || changed?
```

`DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of 'changed?' inside of after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after 'save' returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use 'saved_changes?' instead.`

**When I use `saved_changes?` instead of `changed?` the code won't work correctly anymore, because in this step the record is not yet saved**

e.g.

```
user.email = "hello@example.com"
user.changed? => true
user.saved_changes? => false
```

**Which method should I use instead?** How can I prevent the depreaction warning? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The message means that `changed?` will behave differently inside after callbacks like after_create or after_save. because the record will be already saved you can use `saved_changes?` instead and it will work well on those callbacks

But if you want to use it on before callbacks for example before_save 
then leave `changed?` and don't replace it because it will work normally as previous

If you don't care about if the object is saved or not. you can just check them both `new_record? || saved_changes? || changed?`

For the example you mentioned regarding changing the user email. devise will send the confirmation after save so `saved_changes?` only should work well!

Answer (score 0):

You should to use `saved_changes?` instead.